# Handling multiple fragments in one activity

Tags: android

I have an application that uses a sliding menu as the means of navigation. I have three main fragments that i want to switch between using the navigation menu. Currently i have one MainActivity which is supposed to cycle through these three fragments. The problem is that within each of the three main fragments, i have buttons that, when clicked, should launch another fragment and place the main fragment on the stack to go back to it.

How can i manage this navigation so i am able to use one main activity to swap 3 main fragments and also handle sub fragments on each main fragment?

Hopefully that was clear enough!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a container in your activity. You can replace the Fragments whit FragmentManager.

For example the layout activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

</FrameLayout>
```

And your Activity:

```
public abstract class SingleFragmentActivity extends Activity {


    protected abstract Fragment replaceContentFragment();


    protected int getLayoutActivity() {
        return R.layout.single_fragment_activity;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(saveInstanceState);
        this.setContentView(this.getLayoutActivity());
        this.addFragment();
    }


    private void addFragment() {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = this.getFragmentManager();

        Fragment fragment = fragmentManager
                .findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainer);

        if (fragment == null) {
            fragment = this.replaceContentFragment();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment).commit();
        }

    }
}
```

You can make your activities inheriting from SingleFragmentActivity and overriding the replaceContentFragment method.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options:

- `Interfaces`
- Produce/Subscribe using `Otto`

For the first option, you create an `Interface on the`Fragment` side like this:

```
public Temp foo;

public interface Temp
{
    public void tempSelected(int i);
}
```

Then on your `MainActivity`, you extend the Fragment with that method something like this:

```
public class MyMainActivity extends MyFragment.Temp
```

This will want you to override the methods that Temp provides.

The second option is using Otto with Subscribe and Produce methods. The best explanation for that is [here](http://square.github.io/otto/).

Hope this helps!